# Очистить колонцу в MySql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с колонками
id, user, count со значениями.

Как во всей таблицы сделать так что бы count был равен 0. Какой запрос нужно сделать

Answer (score 1):

Если вы решили обнулить поле count в таблице, то это можно сделать следующим запросом:

```
UPDATE table_name SET count = 0;
```

- table_name название вашей таблицы

Указанная операция произведет установку значения count равного 0 по всей таблице без исключения. Значения будут перезаписаны, отмена операции невозможна без транзакции, будьте аккуратнее.